# How to animate between superviews using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two large views, View A and View B. View A contains a child view, C, which has Auto Layout constraints positioning it in the center of A. I'd like to animate C moving from A to B, which means removing C from A, adding it as a child to B with constraints positioning it in the center of B, then making that move happen over one second.

The problem I'm hitting is that when I remove and add the view and its constraints, the move happens immediately: C jumps from the center of A to the center of B. Is there a simple solution to this that I'm missing? My sequence of events right now is:

- Start the animation block
- `c.removeFromSuperview()`
- `b.addSubview(c)`
- `b.addConstraints(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate the layout process after you change your constraints.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
             animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

if you still see jumping, try converting the point from current Superview ( the current frame of the view in its container ) to New Superview , add subview to new superview to this translated frame ( if necessary with constraints ) , then change constraints to proper values ( and animate layoutifneeded )

Comment: I'm not calling `layoutIfNeeded` right now; it seems to update correctly as-is. Like I said, the whole thing is in an animation block right now, but because I think it fails because I'm not animating the constraints – I'm literally adding new ones because the previous ones get lost when the view is removed from its superview.

Comment: The problem is that you are not calling layoutifneeded , and system does it before the system draws views for the next time after your updates, and system does it without animation , try animating layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: Thank you; I just tried that and it still seems to be jumping. However, if I animate it to an offset off the center (e.g. mulitiplier 0.9) it jumps straight to the center then animates it to 0.9.

Comment: make sure nothing else causes to update layout , update constraints out of the animation block and then animate layout ( right after changing constraint ) , also , when you are adding to the second superview , try first manually setting the correct frame ( so until does layout it will be on the correct , desired place )

Comment: I think - main issue is in removeFromSuperview/addSubview… In this case changes of constraint won't be animated.

Comment: yes , but if you add on the same place on the screen before changing constraints , it should be okay

Comment: Just to let you know: I've got a solution now, and it's about 75% of what you said + 25% of what @Che said below: I move C from A to B, temporarily add constraints for C to position it where it was inside A (even though it's now inside B), call `layoutIfNeeded()` immediately, then remove and re-add constraints inside an animation block to move it from the center of A to the center of B. It seems complicated, but it works – thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What if you will add additional Huge view D? D will cover both (A and B) views. You should do something like

- create D
- C.removeFromSuperview()
- Add C to D with constraints which will place C at the same place as centre of A
- change contraints(C should move to B's centre animated)
- remove C from D and add it to B(update constraints of C)

Something like this

```
- (IBAction)MAGIC:(id)sender
{
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    CGRect fromRect = [self.top convertRect:self.white.frame toView:view];

    [self.white removeFromSuperview];
    [view addSubview:self.white];
    NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(top)-[_white]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:@{@"top":@(CGRectGetMinY(fromRect))}
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_white)].lastObject;
    NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(left)-[_white]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:@{@"left":@(CGRectGetMinX(fromRect))}
                                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_white)].lastObject;

    [view addConstraints:@[topConstraint, leftConstraint]];
    CGRect bottomViewFrameInView = [self.bottom convertRect:self.bottom.bounds toView:view];
    [view layoutIfNeeded];

    topConstraint.constant = CGRectGetMidY(bottomViewFrameInView) - CGRectGetHeight(self.white.bounds)/2;
    leftConstraint.constant = CGRectGetMidX(bottomViewFrameInView) - CGRectGetWidth(self.white.bounds)/2;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.white removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.bottom addSubview:self.white];
                         NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(top)-[_white]"
                                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                                    metrics:@{@"top":@(CGRectGetMidY(self.bottom.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.white.bounds)/2)}
                                                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_white)].lastObject;
                         NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(left)-[_white]"
                                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                                      metrics:@{@"left":@(CGRectGetMidX(self.bottom.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(self.white.bounds)/2)}
                                                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_white)].lastObject;
                         [self.bottom addConstraints:@[topConstraint, leftConstraint]];
                         [view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

[image]